# Increment a Hex value (JAVA)

Tags: java, hex, increment

can you increment a hex value in Java? i.e. "hex value" = "hex value"++

Comment: A value is a value, why does the representation (binary/octal/hex/etc) matter in this case?

Comment: You should try by yourself before asking... so easy to test it and learn by yourself.

Answer (score 17):

It depends how the hex value is stored. If you've got the hex value in a string, convert it to an Integer, increment and convert it back.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
value++;
String incHex = Integer.toHexString(value);
```

Comment: If anyone needs it, if hexadecimal string is long enough to surpass the int, then you need a long type for that conversion.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer**: yes. It's

```
myHexValue++;
```

**Longer answer**: It's likely your 'hex value' is stored as an integer. The business of converting it into a hexadecimal (as opposed to the usual decimal) string is done with

```
Integer.toHexString( myHexValue )
```

and from a hex string with

```
Integer.parseInt( someHexString, 16 );
```

M.

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean with "hex value"? In what data type is your value stored?

Note that int/short/char/... don't care how your value is represented initially:

```
int i1 = 0x10;
int i2 = 16;
```

`i1` and `i2` will have the *exact same content*. Java (and most other languages as well) don't care about the notation of your constants/values.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. All ints are binary anyway, so it doesn't matter how you declare them.

```
int hex = 0xff;
hex++;  // hex is now 0x100, or 256
int hex2 = 255;
hex2++; // hex2 is now 256, or 0x100
```

Answer (score 0):

The base of the number is purely a UI issue. Internally an integer is stored as binary. Only when you convert it to human representation do you choose a numeric base. So you're question really boils down to "how to increment an integer?".